# Build fail with JDK 7 but success with JDK 8 on Travis CI server

Tags: java, maven-3, junit4, travis-ci

Env:

- Java
- Maven 3.5.2
- JUnit 4.12
- Travis CI server

I have some test cases here

```
@Test
public void ItShouldMoveCheckerFrom00to10 (){
    Checker c = board.addChecker(0,0).getCheckerFromLocation(0,0 );
    c.move().Right();
    board.updatedBoard();
    Assert.assertEquals(true,board.checkerExistAt(1,0));
}

@Test
    public void ItShouldJumpCheckerFrom00to20WithOneCheckerAt10 (){
        checkers.add(board.addChecker(0,0).getCheckerFromLocation(0,0 ));
        checkers.add(board.addChecker(1,0).getCheckerFromLocation(1,0 ));
        checkers.get(0).jump().Right();
        board.updatedBoard();
        Assert.assertEquals(true,board.checkerExistAt(2,0));
    }

@Test
public void ItShouldJumpCheckerFrom00to2Negative2WithTwoCheckersAt10And2Negative1 (){
    checkers.add(board.addChecker(0,0).getCheckerFromLocation(0,0 ));
    checkers.add(board.addChecker(1,0).getCheckerFromLocation(1,0 ));
    checkers.add(board.addChecker(2,-1).getCheckerFromLocation(1,0 ));

    checkers.get(0).jump().Right().LeftDown();
    board.updatedBoard();

    Assert.assertEquals(true,board.checkerExistAt(2,-2));
}
```

Travis config:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - oraclejdk7

script:
  - mvn test -B
```

The question is I test successfully with mvn test on local machine
I commit to github, after it ran the test, oraclejdk 8 won't error,
but openjdk7 will all failed with these three test cases.
The log is here, I stamp one of three, the error are same:

```
ItShouldJumpCheckerFrom00to20WithOneCheckerAt10(homework.IntegratedTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at homework.IntegratedTest.ItShouldJumpCheckerFrom00to20WithOneCheckerAt10(IntegratedTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

How can I fix it, or don't do the test with openjdk7?

Comment: shoudl this be (1,0) ?  Assert.assertEquals(true,board.checkerExistAt(2,0)); I don't know checkers so just pardon me on that.

Comment: which is the exact line at this IntegratedTest.java:30 ?

Comment: NullPointerException would generally indicate that your tests were not initialized properly. You should probably provide the non-test portions of your test class to help someone answer your question.

Comment: @tokkov Here is the code spinnet at [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mybaseball52/f2caa20aa0c57cbc2a9c51e4a79eac69)

,@BilboBaggins  and line at this IntegratedTest.java:30 is 
    checkers.get(0).jump().Right();

Answer (score 0):

I find some problem on my code
I need to tear down all my objects because the test runner is context-switch, which means it many run the test while it may switch to another test, so this make my test fail.